# Trigger ng-click inside ng-repeat when ng-repeat item.length=1

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to trigger automatic loadProduct function when `products.length==1`

Bellow my angular code.

```
<div class="prodItem prodItem-nos-{{products.length}} prodItem-item-number-{{$index}}"
    ng-repeat="product in products track by $index"
    ng-click="loadProduct(product.id)"
    uib-tooltip="{{ product.name }}">

    <div class="prodMeta">    
        <div class="prodName" ng-bind="product.name"></div>
        <div class="prodDescr" ng-bind="product.description"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="prodBuyNow">
        <button ng-click="loadProduct(product.id)">Choose</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger function when item in scope changes you can use scope.$watch()

for example :

```
scope.$watch('products',function(oldValue,newValue){
            if(newValue.length === 1){
               executeFunction();
            }
    });
```

**See :**
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-click="if(products.length === 1){ loadProduct(product.id); }"
```

I don't like too much conditions inside ng-click. Being products a scope variable, you can just add this logic inside your loadProduct function, adding a condition at the beginning like

```
if($scope.products.length === 1)
```

and then execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

If, you want to call `loadProduct()` is only one product is there **call it in api which fetched the products**

**Eg:**

```
$http.get("/api/products")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.products = response.data;
        if($scope.products.length == 1)
        {
            $scope.loadProduct($scope.products[0].id)
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-init function 
and check your prodt list in the function

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products track by $index" ng-init="yourFunctionName()">
<div class="prodMeta">    
 <div class="prodName" ng-bind="product.name"></div>
 <div class="prodDescr" ng-bind="product.description"></div>
 </div>  
   <div class="prodBuyNow"><button ng-click="loadProduct(product.id)">Choose</button></div>
</div> 
</div>
```